# 'NSInvalidArgumentException' / '-[AppDelegate fieldChanged:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: iphone, objective-c, unrecognized-selector

The app terminates with a NSInvalidArgumentException when I use this code and I do not know why:

In my `FieldViewController.m` I have:

```
-(IBAction)fieldEntered:(NSString*)sender {
[self.temp resignFirstResponder];
NSString *setFieldEntered;
setFieldEntered = temp.text;
fieldTemp = setFieldEntered;
[(EditViewController *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] fieldChanged:(id)sender];

[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]; 
}
```

It terminates on the `[(EditViewController *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] fieldChanged:(id)sender];` line.

In my EditViewController.h I have -(void)fieldChanged:(id)sender; and in my EditViewController.m file I have:

```
-(void)fieldChanged:(id)sender {
    [fieldArray insertObject:[FieldViewController fieldEntered] atIndex:[fieldArray count]+1];
}
```

Please help me figure this one out. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

From the error, it would appear that the UIApplication's delegate is set to an instance of a class called AppDelegate, whereas you're treating it as a different class called EditViewController.

Comment: Yes. How would I change it to EditViewController?

Comment: @ToddPleeter: Wherever you're setting the AppDelegate as the delegate, you'd use an EditViewController instead. But that seems like a strange design, having a view controller as the app's delegate. Are you sure that's what you want?

Comment: Thanks for your help Chuck. What I want is to have the user place something into the array that is built on the EditViewController. I thought that a delegate should do that for me. What can I do that is within the normal parameters?

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't make sense. May be you forgot to refer to the controller. Should be something like this:

```
[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate].editViewController fieldChanged:sender];
```